# Google Map V2 doesn't allow to draw route?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to draw route between my current location(Like Indore ) to Saudi Arabia.
I am able to draw route between indore to delhi ..but not from indore to saudi arabia.

I tried using intent by passing my lat long and saudi arabia's lat long, but google map app shows no route.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should make a call to the google directions api and draw a polyline on the map manually. You can use this methods:

```
public void setRoute() {
    String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
    downloadTask.execute(url);
}

private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {
    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Mode travel
    //String mode = "mode=" + modeT; Uncomment this if you want choose a travel mode (driving, walking or transit)

    // Departure Time, its neccesary to public transport
    String departureTime = "";
    if (modeT.equals("transit")) {
        long seconds = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
        departureTime = "&departure_time=" + seconds;
    }

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor + "&" + mode + departureTime;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;

    return url;
}

/**
 *  A method to download json data from url 
 */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

/**
 * Fetches data from url passed
 */
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try {
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = ActFullMapOne.this.downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);

    }
}



/** 
 * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format 
 */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData)
    {
        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try
        {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            ApiDirectionsParser parser = new ApiDirectionsParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        //MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        String distance = "";
        String duration = "";

        if (result.size() < 1) {
            Toast.makeText(ActFullMapOne.this.getBaseContext(), "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
        {
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);
                if (j == 0) {
                    distance = point.get("distance");
                    continue;
                } else if (j == 1) {
                    duration = point.get("duration");
                    continue;
                }
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(7);
            lineOptions.color(Color.parseColor("#CC0060FF"));
        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        if (polyline != null)
            polyline.remove();              

        polyline = ActFullMapOne.this.nMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    }

}
```

**EDIT 1**. I just read your post better and I've seen that you only want to open the route on google maps. If you want to display the route on google maps app, use this method:

```
public void goToNavigation() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + modLugar.latitud + "," + modLugar.longitud));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Elige una aplicación"));
}
```

Comment: i tried it my url is this https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?waypoints=optimize:true|22.725425,75.894697|24.016270,45.217712&sensor=false..when i change lat long it works